# Scala: pass implicit argument to function which returns another function

Tags: scala, implicit

Let's say, I have four classes

```
class I
class A
class B
class C
```

And function which takes two arguments, one of which is implicit, and returns another function:

```
def f(arg: String)(implicit i: I): (C => B) => A = _ => new A
```

I have implicit `I` somewhere in scope:

```
implicit val i = new I
```

So, I want to invoke `f` this way:

```
f("123") { c => new B }
```

But I can't because of `missing parameter type error` on lambda param `c`. Ok, let's add this parameter explicitly:

```
f("123") { c: C => new B }
```

Then I have type mismatch: second `f` parameter needs to be `I`, but instead is `C => B`!

I see now two options, how to solve this. First is to simply pass parameter explicitly:

```
f("123")(i) { c => new B }
```

But we don't always have access to implicit values. Also, we can divide function invocation into two expressions:

```
val g = f("123")
g { c => new B }
```

This gives what we need, but code seems cumbersome. I'd like to invoke function simpler.

So, how to invoke such function in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is explicitly writing `apply`.

```
f("123") apply { c => new B }
f("123").apply( c => new B )
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `Implicitly` is a fit for your use case.

`f("123")(implicitly[I])((c: C) => new B)`

`Implicitly` is available in Scala 2.8 and is defined in `Predef` as:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T = e
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can write simple wrapper for such function `f`:

```
def g(arg: String)(fun: C => B)(implicit i: I) => A = f(arg)(i)(fun)
```

Now implicit parameter is really last function parameter and we are able to invoke `g` this way in one line:

```
g("123") { c => new B }
```